build generated in go having different SELinux context than parent directory
In my /home/backend directory, there are multiple Golang projects.
I have used
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t "/home/backend(/.*)?"

and
sudo restorecon -Rv /home/backend

to set the default context for all the directories and their subdirectories/files to 'bin_t'. Any new file created manually (using text editors) has its context set to bin_t. However, whenever I run go build to create a build, the newly generated build has its context set to user_tmp_t. According to this, newly created files should have the same context as the parent, so it should be bin_t.
Why is this happening?

As stated here, transitions are prioritized over inheritance.
So i guess there is a transition matching.
It could be those (not sure):
$ grep user_tmp_t /etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.homedirs
/home/[^/]+/tmp -d  unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
/home/[^/]+/\.tmp   -d  unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
/run/user/[0-9]+    -d  unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0
/tmp/gconfd-[^/]+   -d  unconfined_u:object_r:user_tmp_t:s0

If you don't want your home directory to inherit this kind of user home directory rules, I'd say you should use dedicated path for your application.
Something like /opt/backend could be appropriate. (and make it the home of the backend user if there is a backend user)
